# Braced initializer list for 2-D std::array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, matrix, initialization

How can I initialize array of arrays with `std::array`?
My solution is

```
array<array<int, sze>, sze> arcpp { 0, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ,12, 13, 14, 15 };
for (auto i = 0; i < sze; i++) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (auto j = 0; j < sze; j++) {
        cout << "\t" << arcpp[i][j];
    }
}
```

But I would like something like that:

```
int matrix[][sze] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11},
    {12, 13, 14, 15}
};
```

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to? Can't you use a 1D array, and index like `i * rows + j`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) contains an inner raw array,

> This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member. ...... As an aggregate type, it can be initialized with aggregate-initialization given at most N initializers that are convertible to T: `std::array<int, 3> a = {1,2,3};`.

So you need to add additional braces to aggregate initialize the inner array inside `std::array`, e.g.

```
array<array<int, sze>, sze> arcpp = {{
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11},
    {12, 13, 14, 15}
}};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hlmtEcGJdoNyqi0z)

BTW: Your solution works because of [brace elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation).

Comment: That's it! Thank you